# For Loops in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

I have my code:

```
int time = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
System.out.println(time);
for(int j = 0; j <= time; j++){
    try{
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (Exception ex){
    }
    System.out.println(j);
}
```

It should print out the value of the `j` variable every half second.
What it currently does is it counts, and then spams it to the Console!
What I want it to do is: print out every half second the value of `j`.
(`args` has been defined).
What should I do to make it print out the value of `j` every half second?
Thanks for helping/looking at this thread!

Comment: Think it is not clear what you want to do.

Comment: You have the catch there, but don't use it. It is there for a reason. Use it, maybe it will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Why do you need to sleep anyway?

Comment: What do you mean "it counts" and what do you mean "it spams" (surely it is not printing huge numbers of unsolicited promotional messages at the console ?)

Comment: Works for me. Mind that `args[1]` is the *second* command line argument (`java -jar yourApp.jar first second`). You could try a fix value for testing purposes: `int time = 5;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is fine and it does exactly what you said, which is to "print out the value of the `j` variable every half second".

Perhaps you have some funny expectation of what "print" should do, (perhaps you think it should send it to the printer?) perhaps you have a funny way of observing how it behaves and you mistakenly think it behaves differently.

It is not clear at all what you mean by "it counts, and then spams it to the Console!", but what may be happening is that you may be running your program in a place like ideone, which first runs your program in its entirety, and then displays the output.  So, try the following:

```
        System.out.println(new Date() + " " + j);
```

You will see this:

```
5
Sat Feb 14 11:16:29 GMT 2015 0
Sat Feb 14 11:16:30 GMT 2015 1
Sat Feb 14 11:16:30 GMT 2015 2
Sat Feb 14 11:16:31 GMT 2015 3
Sat Feb 14 11:16:31 GMT 2015 4
Sat Feb 14 11:16:32 GMT 2015 5
```

So, two times per second.  Working correctly.  Case closed.

Comment: Also, my main language is Dutch, so it is quite hard to make a good thread.

Comment: Ah, another happy customer!  C-:=